# Selecting by attributes and making new shapefile using Python ogr only?

Tags: python, ogr

I have a problem making my selected features into a new shapefile with the same projection. I am new to python, any ideas?

Below is my sample script.

[image]

```
from osgeo import ogr
import os, sys

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName ("ESRI Shapefile")

fnVec= raw_input("Enter Filename:")
ofn=raw_input("Output Name:")
ctype=raw_input("Crime Type:")
cyear=int(raw_input("Year of incidence:"))

datasource = driver.Open (fnVec,0 )

inLayer = datasource.GetLayer()

#Execute queries(SQL)
CrimeSQL ="SELECT * FROM Crimes WHERE Crime_Type='%s' AND Year='%s'" %(ctype,cyear)
Crime =datasource.ExecuteSQL(CrimeSQL)

Crime_feature = Crime.GetNextFeature()
while Crime_feature:
    #print Crime_feature.GetField('Count')
    Crime_feature = Crime.GetNextFeature()
```

---

My problem now is to make the selected points into a new shapefile. I made new scripts, but I cannot view the selected points. Here is my sample code:

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr
import os, sys

# Get the input Layer
inDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
fnVec= raw_input("Enter Filename:")
ofn=raw_input("Output Name:")
ctype=raw_input("Crime Type:")
cyear=int(raw_input("Year of incidence:"))
inDataSource = inDriver.Open(fnVec, 0)
inLayer = inDataSource.GetLayer()
spatialRef = inLayer.GetSpatialRef()

# input SpatialReference
feature = inLayer.GetNextFeature()
geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
inSpatialRef = geom.GetSpatialReference()

#Execute SQL
CrimeSQL = "SELECT * FROM Crimes WHERE Crime_Type='%s' AND Year='%s'" %(ctype,cyear)
Filter = inDataSource.ExecuteSQL(CrimeSQL)

# Create the output LayerS
outShapefile = os.path.join( os.path.split( fnVec )[0], ofn )
outDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")

# Remove output shapefile if it already exists
if os.path.exists(ofn):
    outDriver.DeleteDataSource(ofn)

# Create the output shapefile
outDataSource = outDriver.CreateDataSource(outShapefile)
out_lyr_name = os.path.splitext( os.path.split( outShapefile )[1] )[0]
outLayer = outDataSource.CreateLayer( out_lyr_name, geom_type=ogr.wkbPoint )

# Add input Layer Fields to the output Layer if it is the one we want
inLayerDefn = inLayer.GetLayerDefn()
for i in range(0, inLayerDefn.GetFieldCount()):
    fieldDefn = inLayerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i)
    fieldName = fieldDefn.GetName()
    outLayer.CreateField(fieldDefn)

# Get the output Layer's Feature Definition
outLayerDefn = outLayer.GetLayerDefn()


# Add features to the ouput Layer
for inFeature in inLayer:
    # Create output Feature
    outFeature = ogr.Feature(outLayerDefn)

    # Add field values from input Layer
    for i in range(0, outLayerDefn.GetFieldCount()):
        fieldDefn = outLayerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i)
        fieldName = fieldDefn.GetName()
        outFeature.SetField(outLayerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i).GetNameRef(),inFeature.GetField(i))
        outLayer.CreateFeature(outFeature)
print "Process Completed!"     
# Close DataSources
inDataSource.Destroy()
outDataSource.Destroy()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that with your 'CrimeSQL' request you have all desired features selected. You don't need the 'GetNextFeature' method. To test my approach, I created your fields 'Year' and 'Crime_Type' in my point shapefile of next image. There are only two features with attributes ('2011', 'Robbery') at attributes table (delimited by red rectangle).

[image]

Your code was modified by me for adapting it to the conditions of my system: Python Console of QGIS. The SQL request has 'Crime_Type = Robbery' and 'Year = 2011'.

```
from osgeo import ogr
import os, sys

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName ("ESRI Shapefile")

fnVec = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/random_points.shp"
ofn = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/random_points_out.shp"
ctype = "Robbery"
cyear = int("2011")

datasource = driver.Open (fnVec,0 )

inLayer = datasource.GetLayer()

#Execute queries(SQL)
CrimeSQL = "SELECT * FROM random_points WHERE Crime_Type='%s' AND Year='%s'" %(ctype,cyear)
Crime = datasource.ExecuteSQL(CrimeSQL)

multipoint = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbMultiPoint)

for feature in inLayer:
    geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    xy = geom.GetPoint()
    point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
    point.AddPoint(xy[0], xy[1])
    multipoint.AddGeometry(point)

print multipoint.ExportToWkt()
```

After running the code, I used the geometry printed at the Python Console with the 'QuickWKT' plugin of QGIS to visualize the result. Features were selected as expected with your request.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, my problem now is to make the selected points into a new shapefile. I made new scripts, but I cannot view the selected points. here is my sample code: